# Convergence of the Periodization of a Function

Tags: real-analysis

I am working through Stein and Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis, in particular the part about periodization of functions.  In this context, S&S are dealing with functions in the Schwarz space.  They introduce the notion of the periodization of a function, which they define as, for any $f$ in the Schwartz space:

$$
F(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+n)
$$

S&S comment that, because the functions are rapidly decreasing, $F$ converges uniformly and absolute for any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Rapid decreasing functions are defined as those for which:

$$
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|x|^{k} \cdot f^{(l)}(x) < \infty
$$

My question is why this only converges absolutely and uniformly for compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ rather than for all of $\mathbb{R}$.  I think I understand why boundedness is necessary: In order to invoke the rapid decay, you need to know that $|x|^n$ is far enough away from 0, which depends on $x$.  But why is closedness (and hence, compactness) necessary here?  Could you say that the periodization converges uniformly and absolutely for any bounded set?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this just follows from the fact that every bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in compact set in $\mathbb{R}$. Also, a sequence converging absolutely and uniformly on $A$ will converge absolutely and uniformly on any $B \subset A$.

Comment: As to why S&S uses compact sets instead of bounded, my guess would be just that it corresponds to convergence in [the topology of compact convergence][1].


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence

Answer (score 1):

1. My question is why this only converges absolutely and uniformly for compact subsets of $\mathbf{R}$ rather than for all of $\mathbf{R}$.

- Each partial sum
  $$
  F_{M, N}(x) = \sum_{n=M}^{N} f(x + n)
  $$
  is rapidly-decreasing as a finite sum of rapidly-decreasing functions, but the infinite sum is periodic, hence not approximately $0$ for $|x|$ large. Since
  $$
  \sup_{x \in \mathbf{R}} |F(x) - F_{M, N}(x)| \not\to0,
  $$
  the convergence is not uniform on the line. In a sense, rapid decay is not an asset here, but the root of the global non-uniformity.

2. But why is closedness (and hence, compactness) necessary here? Could you say that the periodization converges uniformly and absolutely for any bounded set?

- Yes: If a sequence of functions converges absolutely and uniformly on some set $B$, the convergence is *a fortiori* absolute and uniform on every subset of $B$.

Comment: I think the question then is why S&S mention convergence on compact sets instead of just bounded sets.